# AWS S3 copy file from one root to another using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy

I've been looking for a tool to help me copy content of an S3 bucket into a second bucket without downloading the content first to a local system.

I've tried AWS S3 console copy option but that resulted in some missing.

source Path :- https://s3.amazonaws.com/RedRidingHoodFiles/inmemory/Basket/dffd7780-238a-4750-96b2-9e9ef1b4a4cf/main.png

destination path:- https://s3.amazonaws.com/RedRidingHoodFiles/inmemory/Basket/test/main.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Bucket Explorer which allows you to copy form one Bucket to second Bucket without downloading S3 Object at local.
More details read [this page](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--copy-s3-objects-in-a-single-operation-put-object-copy.html)

**[Disclosure]: I am a developer of Bucket Explorer.**